# Get email from users in my website

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth

I need help to get email from users in my website. I cannot change permissions in my OAuth dialog.

I tried to ask for email permission in the authenticated referral option and User & Friend Permissions but when I click on the preview current dialog, I only get the user basic information.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First off, what language are you using, or what framework? Are you passing your permissions as an array of comma-delimited items to the `scope` URL request parameter, when you are retrieving the oAuth 2.0 access token? It should look like like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1657658326532836257&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com/&response_type=token&scope=publish_stream+user_about_me+user_activities+user_birthday+user_checkins+user_educa
```

Which URL are you calling to retrieve the e-mail address? You should be able to just use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

The JSON field name is simply `email`.